# Dynamic toggle function with jquery?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to create a flexible toggle function with jQuery where I take the ID of the item to be toggled as a parameter. the function is triggered by a link which passes the correct ID to the function.

here is the code at the moment:

```
function boldToggler(itemid){
$(itemid).toggle(function(){
    $(itemid).css("font-weight","bold");},
function(){
    $(itemid).css("font-weight","normal");});
}
```

which is triggered by links like this:

```
<a href="javascript: boldToggler('h1')">toggle style for this item</a>
<a href="javascript: boldToggler('h2')">toggle style for this item</a>
```

is there a way to get this to work? it would save me writing hundreds of toggle functions!

Any help would be amazing, thanks

Comment: the `toggle` function is deprecated in the latest version of jquery

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you mean something like that?

```
function boldToggler(itemid) {
    $(itemid).css("font-weight", function(i, val) {
        return val == "bold" ? "normal" : "bold";
    });
}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/kbQXd/

Comment: I'll upvote this one, as using classes or the deprecated toggle() function is'nt really an answer.

Comment: Your example only works to bold the text. Not working for returning it to normal. I changed the return statement to `return val == 700 ? 400 : 700;` and it worked, fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/kbQXd/1/

Comment: @VisioN : Doesn't work for me. May be some issue at my end. +1 anyways :)

Comment: Yes this is great! lets me pass tags or id's. thank you - if you have a minute, I was wondering what the i and val are passing exactly? would love to learn this, dynamic parameter lists/passing events etc! thanks again! joe

Comment: @Joe This is a handler that receives 2 arguments: index of element and the old value. In order to change the value, the function should return new value. You can read about it here: http://api.jquery.com/css/#css2.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this alternative code may be useful - Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9zxbT/

HTML

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="h1">toggle style for H1</a>
<a href="#" data-toggle="h2">toggle style for H2</a>

<h1>this is H1</h1>
<h2>this is H2</h2>
```

CSS

```
.bold { font-weight: bold; }
```

jQuery

```
$('a[data-toggle]').on('click', function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    $($(this).data('toggle')).toggleClass('bold');
});
```

this completely removes your inline handlers, performs a better separation of javascript and CSS and make use of `data-*` attributes to set the desired selector

Comment: I *swear* I did not steal your idea... looks like great minds think alike!

Comment: Hi guys, nice code and thanks for the advice- for my particular application I need to edit the html directly without using extra classes (its for a cms template editor) - i will heed your advice on the data types in future though! thanks, joe

Answer (score 1):

change your function to this

```
function boldToggler(itemid){
$('#' + itemid).toggle(function(){
    $('#' + itemid).css("font-weight","bold");},
function(){
    $('#' + itemid).css("font-weight","normal");});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Id be tempted to change your markup a bit to make it a bit more jQuery-ish:

```
<a href="#" class="boldToggler" data-selector="h1">toggle style for h1</a>
<a href="#" class="boldToggler" data-selector="h2">toggle style for h2</a>
```

Then use a method like:

```
$('.boldToggler').click(function(){
    var itemSelector = $(this).data('selector');
    $(itemSelector).toggleClass('bold');
});
```

With a css class defined as:

```
.bold{
 font-weight:bold;  
}
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/NTSzs/

Comment: as in my solution you can avoid the class and simply use `a[data-selector]`

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan - Yeah, totally agree. I'll leave this as-is though to demonstrate a slightly different way of approaching the issue. After all, he might want an `italicToggler` too using the same `data-selector` attribute but changing a different cssClass!

Answer (score 0):

you're missing the '#':

```
$('#'+itemid).css....
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the toggleClass method in jQuery.

```
<a href="javascript: $('h2').toggleClass(bold);">toggle style for this item</a>
```

You just need to define the class:

```
.bold { font-weight: bold; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function boldToggler(itemid){
    if($('#'+itemid).css("font-weight") == "normal"){
        $('#'+itemid).css("font-weight",'bold');
    }else{
        $('#'+itemid).css("font-weight",'normal');
    }
}
```